# How do I prove this Triginomerty equasion?

Tags: trigonometry

I got this in a math preparation course I'm taking for college.
Can you please help me proving this?

$$\frac{\sin2a\cos a-\cos3a\sin a}{2\sin a}=\cos a$$

Thanks!

Comment: Hi sorry, I edited and now I guess it's more readable

Comment: It is true that $$\frac{\sin3a\cos a-\cos3a\sin a}{2\sin a}=\cos a$$ For what it's worth, [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simplify%5B%28Sin%5B3*a%5D*Cos%5Ba%5D+-+Cos%5B3*a%5D*Sin%5Ba%5D%29%2F%282*Sin%5Ba%5D%29%5D)

Comment: The first thing to learn before going to college is:- copy/type your question accurately.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Use  [Werner Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html)

$$2\sin A\cos B=\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)$$

and $$2\sin B\cos A=\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)$$

**N.B.** :The problem seems to be wrong : should start with $\sin3a$

Comment: Are you sure it should be $sin3a$?

Comment: @Shiri, Just apply the formulas mentioned

Comment: @Shiri: The identity is surely not correct as written.  The most reasonable way to salvage it is to replace $\sin(2a)$ with $\sin(3a)$.

Comment: Ok, so I guess it's wrong in the paper... Thanks for the answers!